# Обновление данных в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Пытаюсь обновить данные, всё время программа ругается на название таблицы `UPDATE student`, если писать полностью `UPDATE student.tstudent`, то запрос выполняется, но обновление данных не происходит. В чём может быть ошибка?

```
UPDATE student
SET olek='Eksmatrikuleerimisele'
FROM student.tstudent as student
INNER JOIN student.tdeclaration as declaration
ON student.code_student_pk = declaration.code_student_fk
WHERE declaration.code_student_fk IS NULL
```

Comment: Зачем в конструкции `UPDATE` нужны выражения `FROM` и `JOIN`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev потому что нужно обновить данные тех студентов, у которых нет декларации

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Есть таблица студенты, где надо обновить поле olek, есть таблица декларация, из которой я узнаю есть ли у данного студента декларация или нет. Если декларация отсутствует, то поле olek  в таблице студент должно поменяться на Eksmatrikuleerimisele, о умолчанию оно стоит Aktiivne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tstudent
SET olek='Eksmatrikuleerimisele'
WHERE code_student_pk NOT IN (
    select code_student_fk from declaration;
)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Ваш код очень помог!

Answer (score 2):

Так как вы используете INNER JOIN то в выборку попадут только строки по которым сработает условие в ON, т.е. `student.code_student_pk = declaration.code_student_fk`, это условие выполнится только в случае если оба code_student_fk НЕ NULL. При этом в предложении WHERE вы указываете прямо противоположное условие `declaration.code_student_fk IS NULL`. Соответственно под запрос не может попасть ни одна строка.

Всегда перед написанием такого update пишите аналогичный select и убеждайтесь, что получили те строки которые хотели обновить.

Если вам надо обновить те строки в student, которые есть в таблице declaration то уберите условие WHERE. Если же наоборот, те строки, которых нет в declaration то используйте LEFT JOIN вместо INNER.

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам за объяснение! Действительно, только сейчас поняла как все происходило в коде!